# Angular dynamically generated check boxes.Which one is selected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have dynamically generated multiple choice answers with check boxes. I am trying to select with the checkbox witch answer is right. How can I achieve that.

```
<md-list flex>
    <md-subheader class="md-no-sticky">List of Questions :</md-subheader>
    <md-list-item class="md-1-line" ng-repeat="multiQuestion in multiQuestions">
        {{$index + 1}}. {{multiQuestion}}  
            <md-checkbox ng-model="multiCheck">
                {{ $index + 1}}
            </md-checkbox>
    </md-list-item>
</md-list>

<md-subheader class="md-no-sticky">Add more Answers :</md-subheader>
    <md-input-container style="margin-right: 20px; min-width:150px">
    <label>Answer</label>
    <input name= "newMultiAnswer" ng-model="newMultiAnswer" ng-minlength="1">
    </md-input-container><md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="addMultiAnswer()">Add Answer</md-button>

function addMultiAnswers($scope) {
    $scope.multiAnswers = [];
    $scope.addMultiAnswer = function () {
        if ($scope.newMultiAnswer != undefined && $scope.newMultiAnswer != " ")
        {
            $scope.multiAnswers.push($scope.newMultiAnswer);
        }
        $scope.newMultiAnswer = ' ';
    }
```

Comment: What does your `multiQuestions` object look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using objects instead of plain strings in your array:

```
$scope.multiQuestions = [
    { question: "Does it?" },
    { question: "Do you?" }
    // ..
];
```

and in your html:

```
<md-list-item class="md-1-line" ng-repeat="multiQuestion in multiQuestions">
    {{$index + 1}}. {{multiQuestion.question}}  
        <md-checkbox ng-model="multiQuestion.checked">
            {{ $index + 1}}
        </md-checkbox>
</md-list-item>
```

---

If you are really bound to the string array, you can also do something like this:

```
<md-list-item class="md-1-line" ng-repeat="multiQuestion in multiQuestions">
    {{$index + 1}}. {{multiQuestion}}  
        <md-checkbox ng-model="answers[$index]">
            {{ $index + 1}}
        </md-checkbox>
</md-list-item>
```

Then you can access it in your controller:

```
$scope.logAnswers = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.multiQuestions.length; i++) {
        console.log("Question:", $scope.multiQuestions[i], "Answer:", $scope.answers[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you after I added checked to this line I can not checked the checkbox anymore                                                                                 <md-checkbox ng-model="multiQuestion.checked">

Comment: Have you changed your `multiQuestions` array to an array of objects?

Comment: How can I do that. I added my method on the top.